Google Play Console - Staged Rollout in progress but still "In Review" and not being delivered to users
We have managed publishing on and a new version has been sent to the public with a staged rollout. The console is showing that there is nothing currently "Ready to Publish", but confusingly the Staged Rollout at 50% is "In Review"?

Anyway it's currently at 50% rollout with a 13,000+ availability, however the install base for the new version according to the Statistics page is only at around 10 users and our live backend stats show it's only our QA testers from Closed Testing who are running it.
So how is it possible that the staged rollout is progressing daily, yet it's still apparently "In Review" and nobody is getting the app? It surely cannot be both? Does it remain "In Review" until the staged rollout is complete?

